# SMD LED Orientation From Top

Tags: led, surface-mount, dfm

Is there a way to determine the orientation of the LED in the image below?
The blue squares in the corners seem like they are denoting the orientation however it's not marked in the [datasheet](https://industrial.panasonic.com/content/data/SC/ds/ds4/LNJ247W82RA_E.pdf).

[image: SMD LED Top]

This particular LED is the Panasonic LNJ247W82RA.  It's size is 0402.  Is this a common way to mark 0402 LEDs and are there other common markings for the top side of 0402 LEDs?

Comment: There is a detail on the rear if you want to lift it. Though be careful to not turn it as you do.

Comment: Removing it is just silly, unless one is convinced (for example by measuring sufficient voltage across it when it fails to light at a time when it should) that it is either installed backwards or defective, in which case removal will be necessary anyway.

Answer (score 4):

[Polarity Guide of 0402, 0603, 0805, 1206 and most all SMD leds](http://lighthouseleds.com/blog/polarity-guide-of-0402-0603-0805-1206-and-most-all-smd-leds.html)

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: So it seems likely that the bottom of the die is always the cathode and the top of the die which is connected to the bond wire, is the anode.  Is this ALWAYS the case for LEDs?  Can anyone find an LED that's mounted with the cathode on top with the bond wire attached to it and the anode on the bottom?

Comment: @MattClimbs, the same type of LED produced by one technology. With some materials. Location cathode as the basis of them the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try applying a small current through it? (Circuit permitting). If necessary, short the pin driving it to ground to prevent damage - assuming there's a limiting resistor in between.

What do you know about the surrounding circuit? More pics? Circuit diagrams? Back to basics: what does the circuit actually do?

Answer (score 0):

0402s are not normally provided with orientation marks - there just isn't room. They are intended to be assembled using pick&place machines from reels.

At a guess, though, from the data sheet showing the die on a small substrate, and looking at the bond wire location, I'd guess that pin one is on the right. But that's a real guess.

Comment: Pin 1? Which pin is that. Anode or cathode? My guess would be cathode on the right BTW.

Comment: @Trevor- Sigh, Look at page 2 of the data sheet.

Comment: BTW I guessed it the other way round since with three dots it's a triangle, which is different from a bar. But, it were me, I would not have gone with my guess, I would have removed it and verified it.